# Obtain Lagrange interpolation in a point and function

Tags: r, numeric

How do I obtain the Lagrange interpolation in R to find the *nth* order polynomial in *x* that passes through the given *x* points and *y* , which is a function?

Here is a sample to show what I mean:

[image: image description here]

I found simple Lagrange interpolation questions but in there they use y as a function's point not as a function.

Comment: Hi Sezen and welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't think of y as a function. It is a set of numbers obtained from performing the operations on x. So in R you would do `x <- c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2); y <- sin(x) -2` Now y is just a vector of 5 numbers, and you can `plot(x, y)`. You can consider the pairs (x[1], y[1]), (x[2], y[2]), ... etc. as the x y co-ordinates for your calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I didn't think like that. That helps a lot :D